# Notification about new facebook post in android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Is this possible to obtain notification about new post in own android app? I mean, when user add some post on facebook, facebook will post to my application notification about this action and content of new post?
I was searching for solution, but I found only https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications but it is not helpful. 
Thank you for any ideas :-)